# To upload any content on server...what to use?

Tags: c#, web-services

i am making one application,
what to use if i want to upload data on server in C# based application.
i know this names in web services [ i don't know How to use it? ]

1. SOAP,
2. REST,
3. AWS

So my question is,

How many ways i can upload my data file to server?
Do i have to use web service or is their any other way to upload data file?
btw... i am just beginner in C# and web service...so may be u will find this question simple.

---

thanks in advance,
nitz.

**EDIT :**
my app. is on windows based.....
and the files which will be generated from my app. , that i want to store at server.....

Comment: Will you be uploading from an ASP.Net webpage, or a win-forms application ?

Comment: @Russ C..
my app. is on windows based.....
and the files which will be generated from my app. , that i want to store at server.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use any fancy "web service" technology to upload data from a client application to a server. You can create a simple ASP.NET Web handler and save the input file from the request body:

```
public class FileUploader : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       string fileName = context.Request.QueryString["FileName"];
       byte[] fileData = context.Request.BinaryRead(context.Request.ContentLength);
       string path = ...; // decide where you want to save the file
       File.WriteAllBytes(path, fileData);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

From the client app, you'd use [`WebClient.UploadFile` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient()) {
    client.QueryString["FileName"] = fileName;
    client.UploadData(url, inputFileData); 
}
```

This approach eliminates the overhead of protocols like SOAP and posts the file directly in the HTTP request body.

Comment: ..
thanks for your replay....and +1 for putting one example with that....
but i don't know but is this kind direct uploading using http can be useful if user file may be of more then 8-10 mb?

Comment: @Nitz: "Web service" technologies like SOAP are over HTTP anyway. You can split the file and upload in chunks and have the server merge them back. Otherwise, you'd better use other protocols designed for file transfer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to up-/download **files* you should maybe take the [File Transfer Protocol (FTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol).

- [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx)